# I think I made a mistake while doing a Pacifist run

Tags: undertale

My situation is thus; Undyne doesn't like me and Asgore is dead. My ending is so screwed and I am not exactly sure what I may have done wrong.

There was one time where I had killed one of those ice cube monsters but I actually exited the game right after I did so. I was under the impression that it wouldn't count against you if you didn't save the game. Is this right?

Please don't spoil the true ending I just need to know what I've done wrong. I haven't reset yet.

Comment: General way to check if you're on the pacifist route is if you're still Lv1. If you're not Lv1, and have no backups from where you are Lv1, you will need to restart to get the pacifist ending.

Comment: @colorfusion You must have gotten no Exp at all, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If Undyne doesn't like you (which is to say, Papyrus reports that she refuses to hang out with murderers), unfortunately you appear to have killed someone at some point. There's not a good way to determine who that was, if they're not one of the major characters, and even if you knew, there's nothing you can do to fix it.

However, this may not be the tragedy you think it is, because it is impossible to get the true pacifist ending until you've earned the neutral ending. If you haven't finished the game at least once yet, go ahead and do so, and then start a new pacifist run.

Answer (score 2):

Reload your SAVE file. First, check your EXP/LOVE and see if anything went wrong. If your EXP is at 0 and your still at Level 1, then backtrack to Undyne's house to hang out with her. After that, re-fight Asgore, and SPARE him. Also, you don't have to do Neutral twice. After completing the game, reload your SAVE file and backtrack to Snowdin, you will get a call from Undyne. The game tells you what to do from there, so, I'll SPARE your time.